# How can I pass a C# method to a Swift function as callback?

Tags: c#, ios, swift, interop

I want my C# program (A Unity app) to call into iOS native code so that I can communicate with, e.g., Apple Health. I've successfully got my program calling in to run Swift code, but I want to be able to provide callback functions for asynchronous action, and I think I'm missing some detail to allow these to work.

I've got two example Swift functions. `returnTrue` returns a bool immediately, and `sendTrue` takes in a callback to send the bool:

**Example.swift**

```
public struct Example {
    static func returnTrue() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    static func sendTrue(callback: @escaping (Bool) -> Swift.Void) {
        callback(true);
    }
}
```

I've exposed these Swift functions to C using `@_cedcl`:

**Bridge.swift**

```
import Foundation

@_cdecl("Example_returnTrue")
public func Example_returnTrue() -> Bool {
    print("Example_returnTrue started");
    return Example.returnTrue();
}

@_cdecl("Example_sendTrue")
public func Example_sendTrue(callback: @escaping (Bool) -> Swift.Void) {
    print("Example_sendTrue started");
    Example.sendTrue(callback: callback);
}
```

Then I've set up a simple C# script in my Unity project to call these:

**iOSCommunication.cs**

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using AOT;

public class iOSCommunication : MonoBehaviour
{
    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static extern bool Example_returnTrue();

    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static extern void Example_sendTrue(Action<bool> callback);

    public void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log($"returnTrue: {Example_returnTrue()}");
        Example_sendTrue(ResultHandler);
    }

    [MonoPInvokeCallback(typeof(Action<bool>))]
    private static void ResultHandler(bool result)
    {
        Debug.Log($"sendTrue: {result}");
    }
}
```

When I run this, the simple `returnTrue` function works but `sendTrue` crashes. Here's my brief log output:

```
Example_returnTrue started
returnTrue: True
Stacktrace is not supported on this platform.

(lldb)
```

The error given in Xcode is `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` and it seems to occur early within the `Example_sendTrue` function, but I can only see the machine code. Notably, we don't print `Example_sendTrue started`, so I think the problem is with initialisation of this function.

I've been advised to add (and have added) the decorator `MonoPInvokeCallback` to the C# method I pass through so that it's made visible to C, but I suspect I'm missing a declaration on the Swift side to describe what this is, or that I'm not correctly describing the callback's signature to C and/or Swift.

Comment: The line `Stacktrace is not supported on this platform.` is part of the result of Unity's `Debug.Log` call for the line above; it isn't related to the crash.

Comment: I’ve never worked with mono/iOS interop, but I suspect that this bridging is done via C APIs, in which case the only kind of callback you can have is a `@convention(c)` closure. Making that work with a callback (which has access to contextual data), would be a little tricky, but doable

Comment: @Alexander, adding `@convention(c)` to both of my `@escaping (Bool) -> Swift.Void` declarations got it working! I'd be happy to post this as an answer and accept it but as someone with more experience and insight would you like to post this answer? You might do it more justice than I. Many thanks!

Comment: sure thing, I’ll post an answer in a bit

Comment: Finally got around to this, just posted an answer with some more useful context (pun intended) that you might find useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a `@convention(c)` attribute to the callback's signature in both the static function and C declaration defines the parameter as a C function pointer. This is then correctly addressable by Swift when a C function is passed in as the parameter, and can be invoked in the expected way.

```
@_cdecl("Example_sendTrue")
public func Example_sendTrue(callback: @escaping @convention(c) (Bool) -> Swift.Void) {
    print("Example_sendTrue started");
    Example.sendTrue(callback: callback);
}
```

```
static func sendTrue(callback: @escaping @convention(c) (Bool) -> Swift.Void) {
    callback(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct interoperability between C# and Swift, so any interoperability between them has to pass through a C interface, which has no native representation of Swift closures or C# Delegates/Actions.

The closest thing is to pass a function pointer, which must be `@convention(c)`.

---

Here's an excerpt from a thread I started on the Swift forums about something this: https://forums.swift.org/t/add-api-that-makes-it-easier-to-interoperate-with-c-callbacks/62718.

It's more concerned with calling C APIs from Swift than having Swift APIs be called from C, but the function pointer+userInfo pointer idea is much the same.

---

C doesn't have the luxury of closures, and by extension, neither does Swift code that tries to interoperate with C APIs. C functions that want to have a callback have to take a function pointer, which is `@convention(c)` by Swift terms. If you try to pass a capturing closure, you'd get a compilation error:

> ❌ a C function pointer cannot be formed from a closure that captures context

Working around this is pretty tricky, and requires some pretty sophisticated knowledge. (There are Objective-C blocks which can be used in C code, but they're not a standard part of C itself, and there are plenty of APIs that don't use them, so I don't see them as a solution to this problem.)

C APIs often simulate closures by using a pair parameters:

- A function pointer (for defining the behaviour)
- And an accompanying context pointer (for the contextual data). This is often called "userInfo" or "context" and is just a `void *` pointer.

When the callback is called, you're passed back your context as an argument, which you can cast to whatever type you had given it, and unpack your contextual variables from there.

Here's an example simulated C API:

```swift
import Foundation
import Dispatch

// Just a simple example, written in Swift so you don't need to set up a complex multi-lang project.
 Pretend this was an imported C API.
func runCallback(
    after delaySeconds: Int,
    userInfo: UnsafeRawPointer?,
    callback: @convention(c) (_ currentTime: UInt64, _ userInfo: UnsafeRawPointer?) -> Void
) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(delaySeconds) ) {
        callback(
            DispatchTime.now().uptimeNanoseconds, // Some values given to you by the C API
            userInfo // Passes back your `userInfo` for you to access your context.
        )
    }
}
```

Calling it from Swift is a little tricky, in part because you need to be pretty careful with specifying how userInfo's memory should be managed.

Here's an example of one way to call such an API with a userInfo parameter. This approach uses the `userInfo` value to smuggle in a closure which can be invoked. This lets you have the convenience of a normal Swift closure on the caller, while being compatible with the C API. It adds one extra layer of function indirection, but that's usually acceptable.

```swift
func cAPICaller_closure() {
    let i = 123 // Some local state we want to close over and use in our callback
    
    typealias ClosureType = (_ currentTimeNS: UInt64) -> Void
    
    // This is just a simple Swift closure. It can capture variables like normal,
    // and doesn't need to know/worry about the `userInfo` pointer
    let closure: ClosureType = { currentTimeNS in
        print("Hello, world! \(currentTimeNS) \(i)")
    }
    
    runCallback(
        after: 1,
        userInfo: Unmanaged.passRetained(closure as AnyObject).toOpaque(), // Needs `as AnyObject`? A bit odd, but sure.
        callback: { currentTimeNS, closureP in
            guard let closureP else { fatalError("The userInfo pointer was nil!") }
            
            // Retain the pointer to get an object, and cast it to our Swift closure type
            guard let closure = Unmanaged<AnyObject>.fromOpaque(closureP).takeRetainedValue() as? ClosureType else {
                fatalError("The userInfo points to an object that wasn't our expected closure type.")
            }
            
            // Call our Swift closure, passing along the callback arguments, but not any `userInfo` pointer
            closure(currentTimeNS)
        }
    )
}
```